# Proper way to winsorize but ignore nan in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to winsorize a pandas series which contains NaNs. Using mask can escape NaNs, but it only escapes NaNs when finding the percentile value, then replaces NaN also with that value, which is NOT what I want.

For example, df is consisted of 1, 2, ..., 98, 99, Inf, NaN. For a (0.01, 0.01) winsorization, the result should be 2, 2, 3, 4, ..., 98, 99, 99, NaN.

Using winsorize directly yields 2, 2, 3, 4, ..., 98, 99, 99. I tried to mask NaNs first, then winsorize, and at last replace the number by NaN where it is originally NaN:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(1,99))+[np.Inf, np.NaN])
np.where(df.isnull(), np.nan, winsorize(np.ma.masked_invalid(df),limits=(0.01,0.01)))
```

However, the result is now 1, 2, 3, ..., 98, 99, 99, NaN. The smallest number 1 is not correctly winsorized and I don't understand why this happens.

The reason why I don't first drop NaNs and then winsorize is that the index needs to be kept. This is part of a large dataset and other variables for that observation is not missing.

Is there a way (preferablly elegant) to achieve my goal?

Comment: It's interesting that I copied your code and ran it in a jupyter notebook with IPython ('7.30.1') , Scipy ('1.7.3'), and Numpy ('1.21.2') but the result is 1,2,3,...., 98,98,NaN.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to mask it first.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list(range(1,99))+[np.Inf, np.NaN]})
df.loc[mask, 'A'] = winsorize(df['A'].loc[mask],limits=0.10)
```

The reason why 1 is not winsorised is because ignoring NaNs would reduce the sample to 98, 1st percentile would be the "0.98th" observation, which is essentially the "0th" observation, thus 1 is not considered to be winsorised.

Comment: Hi @Rich Andrews - it seems you are the expert python programmer. I have recently asked a question about winosrizing data in python - can you please help? Thanks

Comment: @Rich Andrews - When I run this code i get the error 'NameError: name 'mask' is not defined'. How should I define mask for this code to work?

Comment: @t.pellegrom I don't have this running in a repl, but you would initialize mask to a boolean array based on a condition.  Take a look at the dataframe .where() and .mask() doc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Liu's answer, I guess the mask here is to identify values in the array that one does not want to include in the calculation. In this particular case, the OP does not want NaNs to be used in the calculation of percentiles. To do this, one should first mask the position of the NaN values then feed to the winsorize function. Below is my two cents:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list(range(1,101))+[np.Inf, np.NaN]})
mask = ~df['A'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'A'] = winsorize(df['A'].loc[mask],limits=0.01)
df['A']
```

Liu's correct about the 0.99th observation being round to 0th observation, this can be verified by changing the number of observations from 100 to 102, then the 1 percentile (given by limit 0.01) is assigned to the 2nd observation even after removing the invalid values, in this case, NaN. But also note that how the position is rounded depends on the parameter of the `inclusive` arguments.